# Sqlalchemy save value as uppercase automatically

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When inserting/updating to table, I need the values to be uppercased. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321976/best-way-to-force-values-to-uppercase-in-sqlalchemy-field/65408511?noredirect=1#comment115639700_65408511), but it does not work for me. My table:

```
class User(DBBase):
    tablename = 'user'
    ...
    birthplace = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=True)

    @validates('birthplace')
    def convert_upper(self, key, value):
        return value.upper()
```

When i'm doing

```
conn.execute(User.__table__.insert({'birthplace': 'new york'}))
```

the 'new york' is being saved to db instead of expected 'NEW YORK'. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `User.__table__` is a SQLAlchemy `Table` object. The validator is part of your `User` object and the underlying table has no notion of the validator. The value would be converted to uppercase if you did `u = User(birthplace="new york")`, and then persisted the `u` object.

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you!

Comment: @ShadowRanger updated the answer so the solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321976/best-way-to-force-values-to-uppercase-in-sqlalchemy-field/65408511?noredirect=1#comment115639700_65408511)

Comment: With the update on my answer to address this corner case, this is now a dupe of [Best way to force values to uppercase in sqlalchemy field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321976/best-way-to-force-values-to-uppercase-in-sqlalchemy-field). Sadly, you didn't tag it python or python-3.x, so I can't dupehammer, but at least they're linked now for people who have your problem.