# Python SQLAlchemy Importing Table Names in Lowercase (Snowflake)

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using both pandas.read_sql as well as pandas.read_sql_table, I keep getting the entire table back with all the column names in lowercase.
Is there anyway around this?

I wanted to do some transformations on the data then replace the table in the DB, but it's a pain if doing so changes all the column names to lowercase.

```
#both of these produce the same lowercase columns
    sql = 'SELECT * from "DB"."SCHEMA"."'+"tablename"+'"; '
        
    df = pd.read_sql(
    sql,
    con=engine
    )

    df = pd.read_sql_table(
    "tablename",
    con=engine
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more details on this question?  What is the actual DDL for the tables in Snowflake?  What does the dataframe look like exactly when you do a read_sql()?  What command are you using to write the data back to Snowflake?

Comment: @MikeWalton Just tried to add in the code I used and a screenshot of what the DF looks like.

Comment: Can you confirm you have the supported versions of Snowflake Connector for Python, Pandas and Python installed as detailed here? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html

Comment: Do you still get this issue if you use the recommended `fetch_pandas_all` method instead of `read_sql`? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#fetch_pandas_all

Comment: I only get this behaviour with `read_sql()`. Defining a cursor and calling `cursor.fetch_pandas_all()` return upper case names.

Answer (score 1):

> Snowflake stores all case-insensitive object names in uppercase text.
> In contrast, SQLAlchemy considers all lowercase object names to be
> case-insensitive. Snowflake SQLAlchemy converts the object name case
> during schema-level communication, i.e. during table and index
> reflection. If you use uppercase object names, SQLAlchemy assumes they
> are case-sensitive and encloses the names with quotes. This behavior
> will cause mismatches agaisnt data dictionary data received from
> Snowflake, so unless identifier names have been truly created as case
> sensitive using quotes, e.g., "TestDb", all lowercase names should be
> used on the SQLAlchemy side.

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy

`lowercase` is default behavior in Sqlalchemy. You should not using uppercase in Sqlalchemy or pandas if it is not necessary to. You can either use `"..."` or `quote_names` in Sqlalchemy to specify case-sensitive.
If you insists on getting uppercase columns for all, this post of using events listener could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/34322171/12032355

Comment: Could you provide an example how to use `"..."` or `quote_names` with `read_sql()`, since it's not obvious to a beginner in SqlAlchemy?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its an issue? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html says:

> Unquoted object identifiers are stored and resolved as uppercase
> characters (e.g. `id` is stored and resolved as `ID`).

Comment: I think yes because I'm performing case sensitive operations on the dataframes after I read them.